# Add more fields after a listview.builder

Tags: dart, flutter-layout

I have a statefull layout with a listview.builder inside the builder I have a couple of expansionTile widgets

How do I show the entire list on the screen and add some textform widget below the list?

I have added a Expanded widget around the list to allow for more widgets below it but the list gets cut at a certain point where I want to show the entire list and then the text widgets after

```
class ContactUsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContactUsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String contactRouteName = "/contactScreen";

  @override
  State<ContactUsScreen> createState() => _ContactUsScreenState();
}

class _ContactUsScreenState extends State<ContactUsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Contact Us"),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverFillRemaining(
                hasScrollBody: true,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: salesList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Card(
                                elevation: 5,
                                child: ExpansionTile(
                                  key: PageStorageKey<ContactPeople>(salesList[index]),
                                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                                  childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                                  expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  maintainState: true,
                                  title: Text(
                                    salesList[index].regionDescription,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  children: //[Text("Test")],
                                      salesList[index].people!.map(
                                    (peopleRecord) {
                                      return ExpansionTile(
                                        expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        key: PageStorageKey<ContactUsScreen>(peopleRecord),
                                        title: Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              ClipOval(
                                                child: Image.asset(
                                                  "assets/images/people/${peopleRecord.avatarImage}",
                                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                  width: 60,
                                                  height: 60,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                peopleRecord.name,
                                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            peopleRecord.title,
                                            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                          Text(peopleRecord.cellPhoneNumber),
                                          Text(
                                            peopleRecord.emailAddress,
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ).toList(),
                                  
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15,),
                    Text("Contact us directly",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.black),),
                    Form(
                      key: formKey,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

                          children: [
                            TextFormField(controller: fullNameController,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Full Name",
                            hintText: "Full Name",
                            ),
                            validator: (inputFieldFullName)
                              {
                                if(inputFieldFullName!.isEmpty)
                                  {
                                    return "Please enter your Full Name";
                                  }
                                else
                                  {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                              },
                            ),
                            TextFormField(controller: contactNumberController,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Contact Number",
                              hintText: "Contact Number",
                            ),
                              validator: (inputFieldContactNumber)
                              {
                                if(inputFieldContactNumber!.isEmpty)
                                {
                                  return "Please enter your contact number";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                  return null;
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5,),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if(formKey.currentState!.validate())
                                  {
                                    //Send the email
                                  }
                                else
                                  {
                                    const SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(duration: Duration(seconds: 2), content: Text("Please correct the errors"));
                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                                  }
                              },
                              child: Text("Submit"),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 20,),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    //getContactForm(context, formKey),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
          ),
    );
  }
  }
```

The end result should be that we display the entire list of parent expansion tile, and then only after the textform fields
[image]
Regards

Comment: please show your screen.

Comment: I have added the image in the original query.
You will notice the Listview is just the small block at the top.
The more items you add in the bottom the smaller the listview block becomes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this structure:

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ** first listview **
          },
          childCount: top.length,
        ),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ** second listview **
          },
          childCount: bottom.length,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```